Can we get the number of issues by stream while applying a filter in Coverity (Synopsys) ? or at least the issues's list ( using API)
I tried several commands but none of them worked for me.
I tried the command down below, I want to count all the issues that exist in P1 filter in the project 10158 but it returns nothing
curl -X GET $COV_URL/api/viewContents/project-view/v1/P1?projectId=10158 ID>&rowCount=-1
